# Settext of TextView with AndroidProguardScala

Tags: android, eclipse, scala

I have a bit of experience programming in Java for Android, but I was recently introduced to Scala and would like to code my Android apps in the language. I have eclipse setup with ScalaIDE nightly's and AndroidProguardScala, and I can run the hello world app written in Scala just fine. I decided to change the value of the TextView via the code to get a feel for using Scala, but I can't seem to make anything work for setText.

This is my latest attempt:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity extends Activity {
    def textview = findViewById(R.id.testTV)

    override def onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       val works = "Scala is working"

       textview.setText(works)

}
```

The original way I found posted to do it was:

```
val testText = findViewById(R.id.testTV)
val works = "Scala is working"
testText setText works
```

Neither way works. Both give me an error stating that setText is not a member of android.view.View. Anyone have any experience with this that can help me out?

Here is my XML file:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`findViewById` likely returns a `View`, which doesn't have a `setText` method.  Since you're not declaring a type on `testText`, the compiler is inferring a type of `View`.

Try:

```
val testText:TextView = findViewById(R.id.testTV)
```

so that the compiler knows it's a `TextView`, and the `setText` should work.

Comment: Tried this. I'm now getting a mouseover error in eclipse that says:
    type mismatch; found : android.view.View required: android.view.TextView. I've imported both libraries, i get the same thing if I comment out the android.view.View library.

Comment: In that case, assuming what's returned is actually a TextView, you may have to typecast.  Maybe something like `findViewById(R.id.testTV).asInstanceOf[TextView]`.  Sorry, I don't know the specifics of how the Android libraries work, so there may be something about it that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
val str = "Hi from Scala"
findViewById(R.id.testTV).asInstanceOf[TextView].setText(str)
```

will write to a textview